# How to query mysql Kubernetes pod? Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: mysql, kubernetes

I deployed wordpress and mysql,everything works fine I just want to know how can I access my mysql from command line

```
My services
wordpress           LoadBalancer   10.102.29.45     <pending>     80:31262/TCP     39m
wordpress-mysql     ClusterIP      None             <none>        3306/TCP         42m
```

Describe pod

```
kubectl describe pod wordpress-mysql-5fc97c66f7-jx42l
Name:               wordpress-mysql-5fc97c66f7-jx42l
Namespace:          default
Priority:           0
PriorityClassName:  <none>
Node:               minikube/10.0.2.15
Start Time:         Mon, 11 Mar 2019 08:49:19 +0100
Labels:             app=wordpress
                    pod-template-hash=5fc97c66f7
                    tier=mysql
Annotations:        <none>
Status:             Running
IP:                 172.17.0.15
Controlled By:      ReplicaSet/wordpress-mysql-5fc97c66f7
Containers:
  mysql:
    Container ID:   docker://dcfe9037ab14c3615aec4000f89f28992c52c40a03581215d921564e5b3bec58
    Image:          mysql:5.6
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://mysql@sha256:36cad5daaae69fbcc15dd33b9f25f35c41bbe7e06cb7df5e14d8b966fb26c1b4
    Port:           3306/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Mon, 11 Mar 2019 08:50:33 +0100
    Ready:          True
```

Is there any analogy to docker?
 How to query mysql?

If I try with exec

```
kubectl exec -it wordpress-mysql-5fc97c66f7-jx42l -- /bin/bash
root@wordpress-mysql-5fc97c66f7-jx42l:/# mysql
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Comment: `kubectl exec -it wordpress-mysql -- /bin/bash` and then run `mysql`

Comment: Thanks,but I got access denied no my own machine. Why?

Comment: Did you create secret for MySQL password?  https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/mysql-wordpress-persistent-volume/#create-a-secret-for-mysql-password

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix the issue, you have to set up a password for your MySQL user.

According to the official [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/mysql-wordpress-persistent-volume/#create-a-secret-for-mysql-password), you need to create a Secret object containing your password:

```
kubectl create secret generic mysql-pass --from-literal=password=YOUR_PASSWORD
```

And update your deployment spec with the following part:

```
env:
  - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
    valueFrom:
      secretKeyRef:
        name: mysql-pass
        key: password
```